# gitlab-runner: "local" ansible role not found

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci-runner

The [ansible docu](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/config.html#cfg-in-world-writable-dir) says

> If Ansible were to load `ansible.cfg` from a world-writable current working directory, it would create a serious security risk.

That makes sense but causes a problem in my ci-pipeline fir my project:

```
.
├── group_vars
├── host_vars
├── playbooks
├── resources
├── roles
|   ├── bootstrap
|   └── networking
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory.yml
├── requirements.yml
├── site.yml
└── vault.yml
```

I have two "local" roles which are checked in under source control of the ansible project under `./roles`, but the roles are not found when i run `ansible-playbook --syntax-check site.yml`

```
$ ansible-playbook --syntax-check site.yml
 [WARNING] Ansible is being run in a world writable directory (/builds/papanito/infrastructure), ignoring it as an ansible.cfg source. For more information see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/config.html#cfg-in-world-writable-dir
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note
that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
ERROR! the role 'networking' was not found in /builds/papanito/infrastructure/playbooks/roles:/root/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/builds/papanito/infrastructure/playbooks
The error appears to have been in '/builds/papanito/infrastructure/playbooks/networking.yml': line 14, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
  roles:
    - { role: networking, become: true }
      ^ here
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Obviously cause roles are searched

> A `roles/` directory, relative to the playbook file.

Thus my `ansible.cfg` defined to look in `./roles`

```
# additional paths to search for roles in, colon separated
roles_path    = ./roles
```

So based on the [ansible docu](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/config.html#cfg-in-world-writable-dir) I can use the [environment variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#custom-environment-variables) `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` as I do as follows in the `gitlab-ci.yml`

```
variables:
  SITE: "site.yml"
  PLAYBOOKS: "playbooks/**/*.yml"
  ANSIBLE_CONIG: "./ansible.cfg"

stages:
  - verify

before_script:
   .....

ansible-verify:
  stage: verify
  script:
    - ansible-lint -v $SITE
    - ansible-lint -v $PLAYBOOKS
    - ansible-playbook --syntax-check $SITE
    - ansible-playbook --syntax-check $PLAYBOOKS
```

But I still get the error above. What do I miss?

`site.yml`

```
- import_playbook: playbooks/networking.yml
- import_playbook: playbooks/monitoring.yml
```

`playbooks/networking.yml`

```
- name: Setup default networking
  hosts: all

  roles:
    - { role: networking, become: true }
    - { role: oefenweb.fail2ban, become: true }
```

Comment: roles are searched in `roles` relative to the folder you launch ansible from. You should launch from the base dir giving relative path to the playbook, e.g. `ansible-playbook --syntax-check playbooks/site.yml`.

Comment: Well `site.yml` is in the root and it has a relative path to the playbook. Still the point is it ognores `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` and the only way I can get it working is calling this beforehand `chmod 740 $CI_PROJECT_DIR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the topic is old, but you have a typo in your config file. You are missing an `F` in `ANSIBLE_CONFIG`, so write this instead

```yaml
variables:
  SITE: "site.yml"
  PLAYBOOKS: "playbooks/**/*.yml"
  ANSIBLE_CONFIG: "./ansible.cfg"
```

BTW, it helped to solve my problem

Comment: Bummer, I had to look twice to see what it is - missing F in `ANSIBLE_CONFIG

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Hierarchy setup issue, there is no task associated within the roles bootstrap, networking; Instead looks like the playbooks are in a different folder called playbooks.

Refer directory layout: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html

Comment: the roles have tasks. The thing is that the role and the playbooks have the same name. Still this works fine when running on my dev machine.

Comment: Try checking permissions of the roles for read and execute for the running user